# Delete sharepoint userprofile property using powershell

Tags: powershell, user-profile, user-profile-service, 2013, user-profile-property

This is the script im using to delete the sharepoint userprofile property using powershell.

```
#Load Sharepoint SnapIn
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
} 



# Variables
$path = "path of the xml file"  
# Reading XML File 
write-host -f yellow "Reading XML File Path=" $path
[xml]$xmldata= Get-Content $path
$connectionName = $xmldata.UserProfileProperties.ADName

# start Script

$site = Get-SPSite $xmldata.UserProfileProperties.SPSite
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext $site 
$userProfileConfigManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager($serviceContext)
$connectionManager = $userProfileConfigManager.ConnectionManager 
$connection = $connectionManager[$connectionName]
$propertyMapCollection = $connection.PropertyMapping
$profilePropertyManager = $userProfileConfigManager.ProfilePropertyManager
$corePropertyManager = $profilePropertyManager.GetCoreProperties()
$secMan = $userProfileConfigManager.GetPropertiesWithSection()
$profileTypePropertyManager = $profilePropertyManager.GetProfileTypeProperties([Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileType]::User)
$profileSubTypeManager = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubTypeManager]::Get($serviceContext)
$defaultSubType = [Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileSubtypeManager]::GetDefaultProfileName([Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileType]::User)
$profileSubType = $profileSubTypeManager.GetProfileSubtype($defaultSubType)
$profileSubTypePropertyManager = $profileSubType.Properties


#Remove the manager user property Active Directory mapping
    if($connection -ne $null)
    {
        $pm = $connection.PropertyMapping["manager"];
        if($pm -ne $null)
        {
            $pm.Delete();
            Write-Host -f Yellow "AD Property manager is deleted"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host -f Yellow "AD Property manager is not mapped to any user property"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host -f Yellow $connectionName " does not exists"
    }
```

But when I run this code its giving the following error.

> Cannot index into a null array. At C:\Users\hearttest\Desktop\Roy -
>   Scripts\sharepointuserpropertysetupshellscript\SharepointUserPropertySetupScript.ps1:51
>   char:13
>   +             $pm = $connection.PropertyMapping["manager"];
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Im really new to this powershell scripts please help me out on this asap.

Comment: Your code cannot work as you're trying to do `$connection.PropertyMapping`. But `$connection` is the `ConnectionManager`and doesn't have property mappings.

Answer (score 4):

Your code can't work, too many errors to list.

The following code would delete the user profile property *"Company"*:

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\15\isapi\microsoft.office.server.dll"
$site = Get-SPSite -Limit 1 #get site for context
$ctx = Get-SPServiceContext($site) #get context
$cfgManager= new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileConfigManager($ctx) #get the profile config manager
$propManager= $CfgManager.ProfilePropertyManager #get the property manager
$properties = $propMgr.GetCoreProperties()  # load all properties to variable
$props.RemovePropertyByName("Company")
```

Comment: Hello, can you tell me where exactly is the user profile property values stored? Is it against some list or waht?

Comment: The database of course. Something you shouldn't touch ;-)